# Which Computer Vision technique should one use to detect Road Irregularity?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition

I am researching for my Project which is to detect road irregularity. Given that a image of a road surface and program should tell if it is a pothole, open sewerage hole, speed bumps or is the road clear. 
I have found two techniques by reading various research papers i.e. Mathematical Morphology with Binary segmentation and stereo vision using two camera to create 3D image. 
I would like to know if there are any more techniques one could use to detect road irregularity. (Link to any research paper would be much appreciated)

Comment: Are there any constraints on your cameras or the lighting?

Comment: No there aren't. Lighting will be 100% on all the given input images.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends a lot on how much labelled data you have. Seemingly very difficult image problems can be solved with good accuracy with just 2D images if you have enough training samples available. You should try some off the shelf api to check accuracy it gives with current training data you have for different classes like pathhole, speed bump  or clean road etc. I have hosted a simple to build model for image classification [here](http://demo.nanonets.ai/ImageCategorization/) that needs lesser data. You are free to try it out if it is good enough otherwise look at more complex options like stereo images.